# changing id and text of button according to action

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Math.min() returns the lowest value.</p>

<button style="background-color: #ff0000;"  id="rButton" onclick="maxFunction()" >max</button>
<button style="background-color: #ff0000;"  id="rButton" onclick="minFunction()" >min</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function minFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    Math.min(0, 150, 30, 20, -8, -200);
}
function maxFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    Math.max(0, 150, 30, 20, -8, -200);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It works fine. I now wanted to make id and text on button dynamic.

I want to *show one button at a time*? By default i want to show Max button and when user clicks on it maxFunction() evaluates and give results

```
default:  <button style="background-color: #ff0000;" id="rButton" onclick="maxFunction()" >max</button>
```

and then I want max button to be replaced with min button and it's onclick changes to minFunction() and so it's id.

```
<button style="background-color: #ff0000;"  id="rButton" onclick="minFunction()" >min</button>
```

and vice versa.

Comment: Do you wish to show one button at a time? Like by default you want to show Max button and when user clicks on it maxFunction() evaluates and give results and then you want max button to be replaced with min button and it's onclick changes to minFunction() and so it's id. Also, you should use a unique id for both the min and max button.

Comment: yes...exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following changes, I have updated the minimal code in your current implementation and it works as you are expecting.

In your HTML:

```
<p>Math.min() returns the lowest value.</p>

<button style="background-color: #ff0000;"  id="rButton" onclick="maxFunction()" >max</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

In your script:

```
<script>
    function minFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        Math.min(0, 150, 30, 20, -8, -200);
        document.getElementById("rButton").innerHTML = 'max';
        document.getElementById("rButton").setAttribute("onclick", 'maxFunction()');
    }
    function maxFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        Math.max(0, 150, 30, 20, -8, -200);
        document.getElementById("rButton").innerHTML = 'min';
        document.getElementById("rButton").setAttribute("onclick", 'minFunction()');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script, which has a very simple logic for switching of your buttons.

What it does:

- At start create two buttons.
- Hide them both.
- Show max button only at first.
- When User click max button, hide max button and show min button.
- When User click min button, hide min button and show max button.

```js
(function(window) {
  var createMaxBtn = function() {
    var btns = document.getElementById('btns');
    btns.innerHTML += '<button style="background-color: #ff0000;"  id="maxBtn" onclick="maxFunction()" >max</button>';

  }
  createMinBtn = function() {
      var btns = document.getElementById('btns');
      btns.innerHTML += '<button style="background-color: #ff0000;"  id="minBtn" onclick="minFunction()" >min</button>';

    },
    hide = function(id) {
      var elm = document.getElementById(id);
      elm.style.display = 'none';
    },
    show = function(id) {
      var elm = document.getElementById(id);
      elm.style.display = '';
    },
    minFunction = function() {
      var elm = document.getElementById('demo');
      elm.innerHTML = Math.min(0, 150, 30, 20, -8, -200);
      hide('minBtn');
      show('maxBtn');
    },
    maxFunction = function() {
      var elm = document.getElementById('demo');
      elm.innerHTML = Math.max(0, 150, 30, 20, -8, -200);
      hide('maxBtn');
      show('minBtn');
    }

  createMaxBtn();
  createMinBtn();

  hide('maxBtn');
  hide('minBtn');

  show('maxBtn');

})(window);
```

```html
<p>Math.min() returns the lowest value.</p>
<div id="btns"></div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, an id in HTML is used as a single identifier on the page, and should only be used in 1 element.

As for your question:

```html
<p>Math.min() returns the lowest value.</p>

<button style="background-color: #ff0000;  "id="lButton" onclick="maxFunction()" >max</button>
<button style="background-color: #ff0000;  "id="rButton" onclick="minFunction()" >min</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function minFunction() {
    var min = Math.min(0, 150, 30, 20, -8, -200);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = min
    document.getElementById("rButton").innerHTML = min;

}
function maxFunction() {
    var max = Math.max(0, 150, 30, 20, -8, -200);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = max
    document.getElementById("lButton").innerHTML = max
}
</script>
```

I've updated your function and id's, so it changes and updates the text dynamically.

To change the ID, you should wrap the element in a variable, and change it with variable.id =

Comment: @ Robert...No you  answered something other. I updated my question. I think it was misunderstanding. See updated question.